Need help identifying an IC and a component on a board
I need your help identifying two components on PCB. The board drives the DC motors of a robot toy. The images are attached. Your help is much appreciated.



The ones on the top are HUASHUO (华朔科技) HSU3903 dual MOSFETs.

(Source: lcsc.com)

The one on the bottom is a MX190B dual H-Bridge motor driver made by MIXIC (中科芯亿达). There is no datasheet publicly available as far as I can tell.

(Source: semi-mixic.com, the top line says "Dual Channel H-Bridge Brushed Motor Driver Series")
